# Interact with two keys

Tags: javascript

I have a code that interacts with one key, if you press it you will get a result, I would like to know if its possible to interact with two keys simultaneously for exemple pressing Ctrl and A and it get a result.

Thanks.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 17) {
    document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"stick2.gif\">";
  }

  if(event.keyCode == 76 && 20) {    
    document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "Get Money";
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {    
  document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"shoot.jpg\">";
});
```

Comment: You listen for keydowns and keyups, if two keydowns happen without a keyup, then two keys were pressed at the same time.

Comment: Ok I will try it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode === 76)) {
    document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = 'Get Money';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {    
  document.getElementById('key').innerHTML = 'Give It Back';
});
```

```html
<div id="key"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `event.ctrlKey` if it was pressed or not:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  console.log(event.ctrlKey)
}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler check if Control is down: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ctrlkey.asp